# Align image vertically in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to vertically align a image in swift 3, but the following code is not working, I don't know why?

```
addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: iconImageView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above was fine but it was the following code that I changed:

**From**

```
addConstraintsWithFormat(format:"V:|[v0(30)]|", views: iconImageView)
```

**To**

```
addConstraintsWithFormat(format:"V:[v0(30)]", views: iconImageView)
```

Works fine now